# Converting .pem to a buffer and decrypting

Tags: openssl, aes, rsa

I am working on a proprietary AES code. But at the same time, I am using OpenSSL for encoding purposes. I have encoded a RSA key using the following command of Open SSL:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024
```

which gives me a *`key.pem`* file with "BEGIN" & "END" anecdotes. I have used the following command to encode the file:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc -pass file:./key.pem
```

I want to decode this file in my code. I am reading the key file in the buffer and trying to decode using the AES library but it is failing.
Also, I tried experimenting with the Open SSL decode command for the same which is also failing.

Successful decode:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in file.enc -out file.txt -pass file:./key.pem
```

Failed decode (with contents of key.pem file as buffer in command line):

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in file.enc -out file.txt -pass pass:"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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 -----END RSA PRIVATE
KEY-----"
```

I want to know how can I have the .pem file in buffer so that I can have a successful decode?

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing here is using a RSA key not for RSA encryption or decryption, but **as a password**.
OpenSSL will then use a key derivation scheme to create an AES key from the "password", and use this key to encrypt your text file.

I suppose this isn't really what you want to do (e.g. there is no point to use an RSA key for this), but if your main question is how to pass the file's content to OpenSSL using a buffer, you should look up the [PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html#PASS_PHRASE_ARGUMENTS) section of the OpenSSL documentation. The option `-pass stdin` argument means that you can pass the "password" in the process' standard input stream.